# Determine which columns have changed in rows of a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL Server table which contains incremental `Measurement`s of several different `Attribute`s pertaining to various `Object`s:

```
MeasurementID  ObjectID    Attribute1  Attribute2  Attribute3
100            1           'blue'      111         'large'
101            1           'blue'      114         'large'
102            1           'red'       114         'large'
103            1           'red'       117         'large'
104            1           'cyan'      118         'large'
105            2           'blue'      450         'huge'
106            3           'blue'      450         'huge'
107            3           'red'       450         'huge'
```

My objective is to find an efficient query which, given a specific `ObjectID` tells me which attributes changed and when.  For example, let's say `ObjectID=1`. `Attribute1` changed at `MeasurementID=102` (from `'blue'` to `'red'`), and similarly for `Attribute2` at `MeasurementID=101` and `MeasurementID=103`, and for `Attribute3` at no time (`NULL`).  Conceptually, I'm looking for something which fulfills this pseudo-code definition:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetMeasurementChanges (ObjectID int, AttributeName varchar)
RETURNS @returnMeasurementIDs TABLE
  (MeasurementID int) -- rows of MeasurementIDs
```

I can think of a slow way to do it with poor performance by selecting into a temp table on an `Object`-by-`Object` basis and then iterating through the rows, testing each `Attribute`, but I suspect that's going to perform very poorly.

Anyone got a trick or an analogous question they can point me to?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of SQL Server? Later version have useful analytical functions and earlier versions do not.

Comment: Please see [this post regarding never declaring `varchar` without length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) and [this post regarding always using the schema prefix when creating and referencing objects](https://sqlblog.org/2019/09/12/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetMeasurementChanges -- always use schema prefix
(
  @ObjectID INT, @AttributeName VARCHAR(32)
)
RETURNS TABLE -- use an inline table-valued function when possible
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
  RETURN 
  (
    WITH x AS 
    (
      SELECT ObjectID, MeasurementID, Attribute1, Attribute2, Attribute3, 
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MeasurementID)
      FROM dbo.MyTable -- update this of course
      WHERE ObjectID = @ObjectID
    ), y AS 
    (
      SELECT MeasurementID,
        r1 = CASE @AttributeName WHEN 'Attribute1' THEN ROW_NUMBER() 
             OVER (PARTITION BY Attribute1 ORDER BY MeasurementID) END,
        r2 = CASE @AttributeName WHEN 'Attribute2' THEN ROW_NUMBER() 
             OVER (PARTITION BY Attribute2 ORDER BY MeasurementID) END,
        r3 = CASE @AttributeName WHEN 'Attribute3' THEN ROW_NUMBER() 
             OVER (PARTITION BY Attribute3 ORDER BY MeasurementID) END
      FROM x
    )
    SELECT MeasurementID FROM y WHERE 1 IN (r1, r2, r3)
      AND NOT EXISTS 
      (
        SELECT 1 FROM x WHERE x.rn = 1 
        AND MeasurementID = y.MeasurementID
      )
  );
GO
```

An alternative:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetMeasurementChanges -- always use schema prefix
(
  @ObjectID INT, 
  @AttributeName VARCHAR(32)
)
RETURNS TABLE -- use an inline table-valued function when possible
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
  RETURN 
  (
    WITH x AS 
    (
      SELECT ObjectID, MeasurementID, Attribute1, Attribute2, Attribute3, 
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MeasurementID)
      FROM dbo.MyTable WHERE ObjectID = @ObjectID
    ),
    y AS 
    (
      SELECT MeasurementID, r = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY CASE @AttributeName 
          WHEN 'Attribute1' THEN Attribute1
          WHEN 'Attribute2' THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), Attribute2)
          WHEN 'Attribute3' THEN Attribute3 END 
        ORDER BY MeasurementID)
      FROM x
    )
    SELECT MeasurementID FROM y WHERE r = 1
      AND NOT EXISTS 
      (
        SELECT 1 FROM x WHERE x.rn = 1 
        AND MeasurementID = y.MeasurementID
      )
  );
GO
```

Comment: Thanks @Aaron.  Yours and RS.'s both fit the bill.  Appreciate the help. M

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
if (@attributeName = 'Attribute1')
begin
  insert into @returnMeasurementIDs
  select measurementid from (
  select measurementid,
  rank() over (partition by objectId, attribute1 order by measurementid) rnk,
  row_number() over (order by measurementid) rn
  from table where objectid = @ObjectID
  ) v where rnk = 1 and rn <> 1
end
else if (@attributeName = 'Attribute2')
begin
  insert into @returnMeasurementIDs
  select measurementid from (
  select measurementid,
  rank() over (partition by objectId, attribute2 order by measurementid) rnk,
  row_number() over (order by measurementid) rn
  from table where objectid = @ObjectID
  ) v where rnk = 1 and rn <> 1
end
else if (@attributeName = 'Attribute3')
begin
  insert into @returnMeasurementIDs
  select measurementid from (
  select measurementid,
  rank() over (partition by objectId, attribute3 order by measurementid) rnk,
  row_number() over (order by measurementid) rn
  from table where objectid = @ObjectID
  ) v where rnk = 1 and rn <> 1
end
```

[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/811ec/6)

[Rank](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx) - is used to rank each group by objectid and attribute and it will return 1 when attribute changes.

[Row_Number](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) is used to rank all rows and ignore first row from list of all changed measurement ids so that it returns rows 102, 104 etc.

Comment: Just a couple of comments - you can remove the `IF` conditionals (and collapse the code substantially) by moving the test to a `CASE` expression inside the `PARTITION BY` (as I do in my second example); also you don't need to partition by `ObjectId` if you're already limiting the set to a single `ObjectId`.

Comment: RS, thank you.  As modified by Aaron's comment, I like your approach.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN a.Attribute1 = b.Attribute1 THEN 1 END AS Attribute1,
    CASE WHEN a.Attribute2 = b.Attribute2 THEN 1 END AS Attribute2,
    CASE WHEN a.Attribute3 = b.Attribute3 THEN 1 END AS Attribute3
FROM    Measurements a
    INNER JOIN Measurements b
    ON (b.MeasurementID = (SELECT MAX(MeasurementID) FROM Measurements c WHERE    c.MeasurementID < a.MeasurementID AND c.ObjectID = a.ObjectID))
```

Comment: just add a.MeasurementID I forgot it

Answer (score 0):

Use option with TOP 1 + [CROSS APPLY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) operator

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.getMeasurementChanges(@ObjectID int, @AttributeName nvarchar(10))
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
RETURN
 (
  SELECT o.MeasurementID
  FROM dbo.test90 t 
    CROSS APPLY (
                 SELECT TOP 1 MeasurementID, ObjectID,
                   CASE @AttributeName WHEN 'Attribute1' THEN t.Attribute1
                                       WHEN 'Attribute2' THEN CAST(t.Attribute2 AS nvarchar(10))
                                       WHEN 'Attribute3' THEN t.Attribute3 END AS t1Attributes,
                   CASE @AttributeName WHEN 'Attribute1' THEN t2.Attribute1
                                       WHEN 'Attribute2' THEN CAST(t2.Attribute2 AS nvarchar(10))
                                       WHEN 'Attribute3' THEN t2.Attribute3 END AS t2Attributes
                 FROM dbo.test90 t2
                 WHERE t2.ObjectID = @ObjectID AND t.MeasurementID < t2.MeasurementID                                      
                 ORDER BY MeasurementID ASC
                 ) o
WHERE t.ObjectID = @ObjectID AND t1Attributes != t2Attributes)
```

For improving performance use this indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX x ON dbo.test90(ObjectID) INCLUDE(MeasurementID, Attribute1, Attribute2, Attribute3)
CREATE INDEX x2 ON dbo.test90(MeasurementID) INCLUDE(ObjectID, Attribute1, Attribute2, Attribute3)
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bc688/1)